# Meaning of input.nextLine()

Tags: java, input, user-input

I am taking a course on Java and the "instructor" is introducing how to get the user's input. I don't understand what is the "input.nextLine()" for.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create Scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Output the prompt
        System.out.println("Type in something: ");

        // Wait for the user to enter a line of text
        String line = input.nextLine();

        // Tell them what they entered
        System.out.println("You just typed " + "'" + line + "'.");
    }
}
```

Comment: [Scanner#nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())

Comment: It... erm... waits for the user to enter a line of text and returns it. Just like in the comment right above that line.

Comment: Ordous: Yes I know that but I wasn't understanding this part (English is not my primary language)

Comment: There is a comment directly above the line that says "Wait for the user to enter a line of text". Why is that hard to understand?

Comment: @user3658616 This is plain English, the very basic kind. If you have problems with that - you may want to improve your knowledge of the language before learning a engineering tool based and developed with it and/or posting to a strictly-English only Q&A site. We're keen on answering interesting questions about technologies and programs, not on playing charades.

Comment: @Ordous I am sorry, but people tell me that this forum is the best in solving Java problems. Don't get mad, please.

Comment: @user3658616 I'm not mad, sorry if it came off that way. This is *not* a forum, this is a Q&A site. And unlike a forum, the questions here are supposed to be useful and reused by people who have done their research. Sometimes explaining documentation is fine, since not all docs are good quality. Some things are just not documented well enough. But this question can be answered by someone who doesn't know Java, but simply knows English. Hence it is not exactly a good fit on a programming Q&A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is for reading the next line from the input stream.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
// create a new reference and refer to the input stream.
String line = input.nextLine(); 
// read the next line from the stream (entered from the keyboard) and store it in a String variable named line
```

Answer (score 1):

The java.util.Scanner.nextLine() method advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the next line, waiting if necessary for the line to become available (i.e. the user types out something and presses enter).